# Flutter Mobile App not showing TabBar in release apk

Tags: flutter

I am facing a strange situation. My flutter app was working fine & no major changes were made in Tab bar. Somehow the Tab bar shows perfectly in Emulator and connected physical device. But the moment I build an APK and run on same physical device, Tab bar disappears.

I have create a Minimal Code from my main project mimicking the same behaviour

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Unige_App());
}

class Unige_App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MyApp();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        initialIndex: 0,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(getScreenHeight() * .2),
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              title: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Hero(
                      tag: 'logo',
                      child: Container(
                          height: kToolbarHeight,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 20.0, left: getScreenWidth() * .1),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.hail,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: getScreenWidth() * .2),
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.logout,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ]),
              bottom: TabBar(
                controller: tabController,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: const Text(
                        "My Products",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: const Text(
                        "My Feedback",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: const Text(
                        "My Profile",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: [MyProductsPage(), MyFeedback(), MyProfile()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  MyProductsPage() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "My Products",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.red),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  MyFeedback() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "My Feedback",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.orange),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  MyProfile() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "My Profile",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.green),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  double getScreenHeight() {
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;

    //Size in physical pixels
    var physicalScreenSize = window.physicalSize;
    var physicalHeight = physicalScreenSize.height;
    var logicalScreenSize = window.physicalSize / pixelRatio;

    var padding = window.padding;

//Size in logical pixels

    var logicalHeight = logicalScreenSize.height;

//Safe area paddings in logical pixels

    var paddingTop = window.padding.top / window.devicePixelRatio;
    var paddingBottom = window.padding.bottom / window.devicePixelRatio;
    return logicalHeight - paddingTop - paddingBottom;
  }

  double getScreenWidth() {
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;

    //Size in physical pixels
    var physicalScreenSize = window.physicalSize;
    var physicalWidth = physicalScreenSize.width;
    var logicalScreenSize = window.physicalSize / pixelRatio;
    var logicalWidth = logicalScreenSize.width;
    var padding = window.padding;

//Safe area paddings in logical pixels
    var paddingLeft = window.padding.left / window.devicePixelRatio;
    var paddingRight = window.padding.right / window.devicePixelRatio;
    var paddingTop = window.padding.top / window.devicePixelRatio;
    var paddingBottom = window.padding.bottom / window.devicePixelRatio;
    return logicalWidth - paddingLeft - paddingRight;
  }
}
```

Screenshots of above code:
Physical device (Samsung phone) running from Android studio
[image]

Same Physical Device(Samsung phone) running APK (Tabbar disappeared)
[image]

The same behaviour is for my project as well as the minimal code above, Can someone help me ?

**UPDATE**

i tried running release version on attached physical device using:

```
 $ flutter devices
$ flutter run -d <device id> --release
```

But still get the disappeared Tab bar. Also the console is clean as in no error messages related to layout etc.

Comment: can you double check on the debug console that there is no error shown there.

Comment: Yes, no errors there, either on running it on Debug mode or building APK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the issue on flutter github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116546

I got the solution by an expert that, the methods getScreenHeight() & getScreenWidth() may be returning 0 as sizes because in release mode window.physicalSize sometimes returns 0 in android.

As suggested, i switched to MediaQuery for ascertaining the screen size & it worked !